# formatting currency when using DisplayNameFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I change the display from 50000 to 500.00?

```
<div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
</div>
```

This works but its pretty ugly.

```
$@((Model.Price / 100)).00
```

Input:  **50000**
Output: **$500.00**

Its got to be a better cleaner way to do this.

Also tried this but I get errors.

```
@((Model.Price / 100).ToString("c"))
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

apply this in your model

```
      [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
      public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: I am getting a wrong result: **$500,000.00** when entered **50000** which is equivalent to $500

Comment: value = 50000 should display $500.00  OR value = 500000 should display $5,000.00